# Multiple blank spaces in flash messages (CakePHP)

Tags: php, html, css, cakephp

I am trying to get some blank spaces in a row in a flash message but I don't manage to do so.

This is how my code looks:
`$this->Flash->success(__('My message     goes here')`

This is what I get:
`My message goes here`

This is what I want:
`My message     goes here`

Thanks in advance!

**SOLUTION**: `$this->Flash->success(__('My message &nbsp; goes here'), ['escape' => false])`

Comment: Flash messages are rendered with HTML, and HTML compresses duplicate whitespace. Replace those spaces with `&nbsp;`s and you should be fine.

Comment: But then I guess you need to stop escaping: `->success(__('...'), ['escape' => false])` for it to render actual HTML.

Comment: Combining both things it works perfectly!